# Is it possible to use Speech Recognition module in my application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, voice-recognition

I saw a picture in @Matthieu's blog http://wp7wonders.wordpress.com/ yesterday(sorry,I can't find it now.
This picture have a textbox within a microphone icon just like the search page in phone.

My qusetion is can I use this feature in my application?How?

[image: Search bar has an icon which can use to turn on Speech Recognition Input]

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no on-device or framework assemblies that you can use to perform speech recognition directly in your applications. However, Kevin Marshall has a [blog post](http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/category/speech-recognition/) that shows how to implement speech recognition by using Web services that use System.Speech and the microphone.

Comment: It seems that it is not easy.I don't have a server to run this stuff(my server is linux and java).Thank you any way.